# Sticky Header in mobile devices Jupiter theme

Tags: wordpress, mobile, sticky

How can I have Sticky Header on mobile devices using Jupiter theme? In my WordPress theme, I enable the sticky header but it doesn't work on mobile devices. How can I fix this?

It's also possible to check in their website:
https://demos.artbees.net/jupiter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is css code you can use to get sticky header on mobile.
Try this one:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
     .mk-header {
         position: fixed;
     }
      body #theme-page {
         padding-top: 90px !important;
    }}
```